# What type of switch would this be? 4PDT or something else?

Tags: switches, circuits

I’m having trouble reading this switch diagram. The description says the switch contains 6 internal switches but does that mean the that’s a 6PDT? Or is it a 4PDT? Or something else entirely. I believe it’s an on-on switch so would forward and back position of the switch count as two switches or one? Any guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why did you remove the switch drawing?  My answer doesn't make much sense without the drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Your drawing shows a Double Pole Double Throw (DPDT) relay.  If the zigzag at the top of the pinout implies more parts of the device are shown elsewhere, then it would be part of a package with two or more DPDT relays.

To me, the coils shown above and below the contacts indicate that the thing is a latching relay rather than a simple switch.

From your description, I would assume the complete device contains six DPDT relays

Answer (score 0):

The "zag" mark seems to suggest that the pattern repeats, so there should be 6 poles each with two positions.